# Picking out the ID from a URL, add it to the end of a link with a new URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I send out emails to my companys customers, where each customer has a unique ID. When they click a button in mail, they go to a landing page in wordpress where I save their ID in the URL. for example:

http://www.example.com/?1234567

Where 1234567 is the customer ID number

What I want to do is have a button with a link from the landing page that goes to a different domain, and also send the ID with the new url, tex (When the user clicks on the button, the address will now be):

http://www.newdomain.com/?1234567

How to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current url using

```
window.location.href
```

When you have the current URL you can split using `?`, to get the id. Attach the id to the new URL. That's it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query string using either

Javascript

```
window.location.search
```

PHP

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

So to create a link with this you can do something like either:

Javascript

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.newdomain.com/' + window.location.search;">LINK</a>
```

PHP

```
<a href="http://www.newdomain.com/?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.search` to get the id. Note that in the example the id will be `undefined` because the iframe doesn't contain an id in the url.

```js
$(function() {

  var id = window.location.search.split('?')[1]; // get the id
  
  var link = $('#domainLink'); // get a refernce to the link

  var currentLink = link.prop('href'); // get the current url

  link.prop('href', currentLink + '?' + id); // change the url to include the id

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="domainLink" href="http://whatever.com">link to another domain</a>
```